# postgres/data/pgdata is not a valid data directory in kubernetes workload

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform

The workload 'datastore' inside our Kubernetes cluster has stopped working giving a CrashLoopBackOff error.

I have tried accessing logs for this pod and it gives the following details:

FATAL:  "/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata" is not a valid data directory
DETAIL:  File "/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata/PG_VERSION" does not contain valid data.
HINT:  You might need to initdb.

Has anybody else faced this error before? What has suddenly caused this to happen and how can I go about fixing it?

Thanks

Comment: Could you please add the image you are using and the deployment yaml files?

Comment: Already answered here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51093171/docker-not-recognizing-postgresql-data-directory